# prevent from window.location to child div Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working with this code, anytime I click on the div it goes to the url...

**HTML**

```
    <div class='gotoPost' data-href='post?i=24'>[text]</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $(function() { 
     toUrl = function(){ 
         var GoToUrl = $(this).data('href');
         var redirect = GoToUrl;
         window.location = redirect;
      }
 });

 $(function() {$(".gotoPost").on('click',toUrl);});
```

**PROBLEM**
Now I want to add a absolute-positioned `div` at the top of the container, but anytime I click on it. (to show a Lightbox) it goes to the url...how do I prevent it from going to the url? *I want when clicked the child div,it doesnt go to the url.*

```
 <div class='gotoPost' data-href='post?i=24'>[text]

       <div class=ShowLightBox>3</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You're using `window.location = <url>`, which of course means it will redirect. Remove that line and you'll be ok.

Comment: How is it a problem when you are explicitly setting this to `window.location`

Comment: But what I want is when clicked the child it doesnt go to the url. because this child has another function.

Comment: then remove `window.location = redirect` and make it run the function it is supposed to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## So Your question is..

```
<div class='gotoPost' data-href='post?i=24'>
    [text]
    <div class=ShowLightBox>3</div>
</div>
```

If you click 'showlightbox' div, it doesn't redirect to other page,
but when you click other area of 'gotoPost', then you want to redirect page. right?

## Solution

So here's the solution:

```
$(function() { 
    toUrl = function(e){ 
        if (e.target.classList.contains('gotoPost')) {
            var GoToUrl = $(this).data('href');
            var redirect = GoToUrl;
            window.location = redirect;
        }
    }
});
$(function() {$(".gotoPost").on('click', toUrl);});
```

If you use call-back function with JS, when event happends it will call call-back function with 'EVENT' object, which contains 'e.target' - HTML Element you've click.

the code above check if your click event is targeting 'gotoPost' directly not inside HTML element. So this would work for you! :)

ps. Checkout "Event Delegation with JavaScript".

Comment: thank you it has sense, but this line doesnt work in my code ` if (e.target.classList.includes('gotoPost')) { ` has you already test it?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. not `includes` but `contains`. I've edited my answer!

Comment: At the end I used your solution, works pretty well thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the click event on `.ShowLightBox` from propagating. For example:

```
$('.ShowLightBox').on('click', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();

   // Open light box
});
```

*Ref:* https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: `e.stopPropagation();` awesome line!